# Copy formatting to macro

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I have a workbook that the workbook formatting is changed regularly, however once changed (maybe weekly or monthly) then going forward until it is changed again a macro needs to replicate that format. Changing the VBA to account for the new formatting each time is very time consuming. Is it possible to format a workbook and then copy the formatting easily to VBA (after the fact not like a macro record) for future use?

In the past I have since used a hidden sheet within the workbook where the macro runs and I essentially copy/paste that into the sheet I am working with. This works but has the downside of when making changes I first need to copy data over to the "template" sheet to ensure everything is correctly aligned with new data.

Possibly some kind of macro that iterates through all cells of a range and outputs to the immediate window the VBA code needed to re-create the formatting?

Basically any ideas will help :)

Comment: You can either use the macro recorder or you need to write that VBA code yourself. What you asked for does not exist. • Actually using a template sheet like you did would be the easiest approach I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many formatting options that simply storing them as separate options will take far more space than just a duplicate template sheet. Just run the first code to update your template, and the second to copy it back:

```
  option Explicit
  Const TemplatesheetName = "mytemplate"

  Sub CopyFormatting
  dim ws as worksheet
   dim source as worksheet
  set source = activesheet
  for each ws in worksheets
      if ws.name = templatesheetname then
         exit for
      end if
  next ws
  if ws is nothing then 
      set ws = worksheets.add
      ws.name = templatesheetname
  end if
  ws.usedrange.clearformats
  source.usedrange.copy
  ws.range("a1").pastespecial xlpasteformats
  ws.visible = xlveryhidden
  end sub

  Sub BringBackFormats
  dim ws as worksheet
  for each ws in worksheets
      if ws.name = templatesheetname then
         exit for
      end if
  next ws
  if ws is nothing then 
       msgbox "No template found",vbokonly,"Unabl;e to run"
  else
      ws.cells.copy
      activesheet.range("a1").pastespecial xlpasteformats
 end if
 exit sub
```

(written on my phone, can't check the code, there may be typos)

Comment: Oh, I have no clue why I did no think of a macro just to update the secondary template sheet... Duh... thank you! I do not know if the code would work but it looks pretty solid for having written it on your phone. I will definitely be using this method.